# Generate 500 random numbers in 30 rows with uniform dist

Tags: r

Trying to do the following. Generating 30 rows of 500 random numbers with uniform (0,1) distribution.

But it only has integers, when i need numbers with decimal places.

Comment: `matrix(runif(60 * 300), ncol = 60)` and of course there is `rexp` for achieving your actual objective.

Answer (score 3):

Your `runif` command is incorrect. Do :

```
df<-data.frame(replicate(60,runif(300,0,1)))
```

As pointed out by Tim and Roland, it is best (faster) to use :

```
df<-matrix(runif(60*300),ncol=60)
```

For `runif`, the first argument is the number of observations, then the min and then the max, separated by a comma.

```
 df[1:5,1:5]
         X1         X2        X3        X4        X5
1 0.4375043 0.76986901 0.1154772 0.8861121 0.0275067
2 0.4024352 0.19291795 0.7496475 0.5159706 0.8768299
3 0.3164539 0.02212373 0.2091863 0.2792025 0.5175030
4 0.2496215 0.51070780 0.8462652 0.2604232 0.9109863
5 0.8450932 0.68503812 0.2391174 0.0220619 0.4943907
```

As for your exponential distribution, if I am correct, if U is a uniform distribution between 0 and 1 then -ln(U)/lambda is an exponential distribution with a lambda parameter. The ln function is `log` in R.

With the following code :

```
require(fitdistrplus)
set.seed(1)
df<-runif(100000,0,1)
df<-(-log(df))
png('fit.png')
descdist(df)
dev.off()
```

you get this plot : the data seems to follow an exponential distribution (as expected)

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Would you know how to apply inversion to it?

Comment: You mean like `-log(df)/lamda` = `-log(df)` as you want `lambda=1`?

Comment: `replicate` is useless and slows things down! Try `rbenchmark::benchmark(runif(100*100), replicate(100, runif(100)))` - the `replicate` solution is 2x slower.

Comment: I need to apply Gamma inversion. How can i label my columns as x and my numbers as y?

Comment: If you want to give names to your matrix columns and rows use `rownames` and `colnames`. Is that what you wanted ?